# GSON Json Mapping for HashMap Nested Object

Tags: java, json

I have a json context like below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "details": {
      "en-CA": {
        "languageCode": "en-CA",
        "isPrimaryLocale": false
      },
      "en-US": {
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "isPrimaryLocale": true,
        "languageDisplayName": "English (United States)",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To map it with GSON in java:

I created this classes:

```
public class ApiResponseSingleDto
{
    private ResponseDetail data;
}

public class ResponseDetail
{
    private ResponseDetails details;

    @Getter
    public static class ResponseDetails
    {
        public HashMap<String, LocaleDetail> row = new HashMap<>();
    }
}

public class LocaleDetail
{
    private String languageCode;
    private Boolean isPrimaryLocale;
    private String languageDisplayName;
}
```

When I try to map json to Java POJO class, HashMap doesn't work. Is there any suggestion?

To map it:

```
GSON.fromJson("...json", Type type...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to replace:

```
public class ApiResponseSingleDto
{
    private ResponseDetail data;
}

public class ResponseDetail
{
    private Map<String, LocaleDetail> details;
}

public class LocaleDetail
{
    private String languageCode;
    private Boolean isPrimaryLocale;
    private String languageDisplayName;
}
```

Also json seems to be incorrect: `"languageDisplayName": "English (United States)",`

should be just `"languageDisplayName": "English (United States)"`

One more note: I believe you should have public fields or at least getters for them